# How do I adjust the left margin in Emacs (noX)?

Tags: emacs

Currently the text is right up against the left edge of the terminal window, which is somewhat annoying.  I would like there to be a small margin, without line numbers, or a visual line.  I am aware of the fringes, however fringe-mode only seems to work in the GUI version.  Ideally, I would like the margins to be adjusted on the fly, depending on the window size, to center the text body of a particular width, which is then filled properly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could add the following to your Emacs init file to add a 2 character margin (change to suit) to the left and right sides of every window:

```
(add-hook 'window-configuration-change-hook
          (lambda ()
            (set-window-margins (car (get-buffer-window-list (current-buffer) nil t)) 2 2)))
```

This works in a terminal Emacs.

Comment: Yes, `(set-window-margins nil 1)` will instantly give a left margin of one char to the current window (that's the `nil`). This works with `emacs` in the Linux console. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
(global-linum-mode t)
(setq linum-format " ")
```

Not elegant but works.

Thanks for Emanuel Berg's comment.

Comment: Didn't get this to work. Perhaps you need to enable line enumeration as well? (The only function I found was `line-number-mode`, but that had to do with displaying the line number of the cursor in the bar above the minibuffer.)