# Margin width toggle in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp, margins

I'm using the following snippet to set a 1-character margin to both edges of an Emacs buffer ([thanks to zev!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251784/how-do-i-adjust-the-left-margin-in-emacs-nox/7251942#7251942)):

```
(add-hook 'window-configuration-change-hook
      (lambda ()
        (set-window-margins (car (get-buffer-window-list (current-buffer) nil t)) 1 1)))
```

However, I'd also like to have another configuration that gives me very wide left and right margins (say, 30 chars). How could I assign a hotkey for toggling between these two states, possibly *over all buffers*?

I tried the following:

```
(global-set-key [(control f10)]
(add-hook 'window-configuration-change-hook
      (lambda ()
        (set-window-margins (car (get-buffer-window-list (current-buffer) nil t)) 30 30))))
```

But got this error:

```
Wrong type argument: commandp, ((lambda nil (set-window-margins (car (get-buffer-window-list (current-buffer) nil t)) 30 30)) (lambda nil (set-window-margins (car (get-buffer-window-list (current-buffer) nil t)) 1 1)) frame-local-variables-check)
```

Where am I wrong? Thanks for any explanations. Cheers!

**EDIT:**

I am well aware of [darkroom-mode](http://www.martyn.se/code/emacs/darkroom-mode/) that provides such wide margins. But it doesn't seem to work flawlessly on my XP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you going:

```
(global-set-key [C-f10]
     (lambda ()
     (interactive)
     (set-window-margins (car (get-buffer-window-list (current-buffer) nil t)) 30 30)))
```

Your example does not work as the global-set-key is expecting the second argument to be a `command`, hence the error. Also your key definiton is a little odd.

For your comment:

```
(walk-windows (lambda (window) (set-window-margins window 30 30)) nil t)
```

Comment: However, how could I make this work over **all** buffers? Setting `(get-buffer-window-list (buffer-list))` didn't help. Thanks!

Comment: @mart `set-window-margin` does not work on buffers, it works on windows. I added the code but suggest you read the Elisp info pages: `M-x info RET m Elisp RET`

Comment: thank you. I'm only getting to konw Elisp/Emacs, hence this obviously very "basic" question. But I really needed to get this thing to work.

Comment: @mart That's why I pointed you to the manual. I have never used any of those functions but simply figured it out by looking at the doc of them, e.g. `C-h f walk-windows RET`. You'll get the hang of it sooner or later.